# Any concise way to calculate n * (n+1) / 2 and handling overflow at the same time

Tags: c, overflow

I am trying to implement `n * (n + 1) / 2` knowing that `n` is an `int` <= 2^16 - 1 (this guarantees that `n * (n + 1) / 2 <= 2^31 - 1` so there is no overflow).

Then we know that `n * (n + 1) / 2` is guaranteed to be non-negative integer. When calculating this value in a program, though, if we do multiplication `n *(n + 1)` first, we might get into integer overflow problem. My idea is to use a clumsy condition:

```
int m;
if (n % 2 == 0) {
    m = (n / 2) * (n + 1);
} else {
    m = n * ((n + 1) / 2);
}
```

Is there any more concise way of doing this?

Comment: `long tmp = n * (n + 1); m = tmp / 2; ` ?

Comment: @MichelBillaud `long` might still be 32 bits on some systems (e.g. Microsoft Visual C++ compiler, even on 64-bit systems).

Comment: Well, @Some programmer dude, `long long tmp`, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/s3f49ktz.aspx

Comment: @MichelBillaud : Comments are for comments; your "comment" is an anaswer.

Comment: @Clifford FWIW, people provide answers to questions in the comments *all the time*.

Comment: @steveSummit ; I know, and it is clearly contrary to SO guidelines. It is unhelpful for those using the site Search or even Google since the comments are not indexed AFAIK.  I might have voted for it as an answer; instead I stole it!

Answer (score 4):

There is a more concise way to write your test using the ternary operator:

```
int m = (n % 2 == 0) ? (n / 2) * (n + 1) : n * ((n + 1) / 2);
```

But it is likely to generate the exact same code.

You could take advantage of the extra precision `long long` is guaranteed to provide (at least 63 value bits):

```
int m = (long long)n * (n + 1) / 2;
```

Whether this is more or less efficient than the test version will depend on the target CPU and the compiler version and options. This version is simpler to read and understand, which is valuable.  Adding a comment to explain why the result will be in range would be useful.

Derived from a suggestion by Amadeus, here is a more concise, but much less readable alternative, that does not use 64-bit arithmetics:

```
int m = (n + (n & 1)) / 2 * (n + 1 - (n & 1));
```

Demonstration:

- if `n` is odd, we get `m = (n + 1) / 2 * n;`
- if `n` is even, we get: `m = n / 2 * (n + 1);`.

Comment: Strictly the last part is an _explanation_ or _demonstration_ rather then a "proof", but that is somewhat pedantic, since mathematical proof is not required here.

Answer (score 3):

What do you think about:

```
m = ((n + (n & 1)) >> 1) * ( n + !(n & 1));
```

Explanation:

This solution try to achieve two objectives:

- Do not overflow
- Avoid to use `if then else` condition, and be pipeline friendly

To avoid overflow we first divide and the multiply. Once division is done to half the number (by 2) it has an interesting property: if number is odd the division is exact and can be done by a simple **right sifting** by 1.

So, to guarantee that the number is odd without `if then else` condition, we use the following trick:

If number is odd, it means that it lower bit is zero (captured by anding it with 1), otherwise it is even. Therefore if number is odd, we divide it by 2, otherwise, we first add 1, to make sure that it is odd and the divide.

In other words, this solution is equivalent to:

```
if ( n is odd )
    m = (n >> 1) * (n + 1);
else
    m = ( (n + 1) >> 1) * n;
```

Comment: It does not work because `n + n & 1` is evaluated as `(n + n) & 1`, which is always `0`.  Trying to figure `m = ((n + (n & 1)) >> 1) * (n + ~(n & 1));` without a pen and paper gives me a headache.

Comment: I'm afraid there is another problem: `(n + ~(n & 1))` should be `(n + !(n & 1))`, which is more readable as `(n + 1 - (n & 1))`.

Comment: @DavidBowling Thanks for pointing my error. You can check an example running here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be688374e016e970

Comment: @chqrlie Correct the code. Example here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be688374e016e970

Comment: The idea was a good one, even if not correctly implemented the first time. I much prefer the way @chqrlie has it formulated, as this is _much_ more legible in my opinion. Still, +1 for a good idea; but I hope that chqrlie gets some more votes, since I think that his is a better answer.

Comment: @DavidBowling thanks for upvote, while Chqrlie has summarized the answers, I do not think mine is less readable. But taste is taste. And I really do not know if compiler will optimize the division by 2 for a simple right shifting

Comment: @Amadeus: the compiler will optimize the division by 2 as a shift plus an adjustment for the case of negative values. If `n` has an unsigned type, a simple shift is semantically equivalent to a division by 2. Regarding readability, your solution or my derived version are both non obvious, much more difficult to comprehend than `int m = (long long)n * (n + 1) / 2;`

Comment: I `think` it deserves some explanation.  See @chqrlie for example.  A solution explained or demonstrated is more likely to be used than a "mystery" solution that needs to be thought about.  Inviting us to _"think about"_ it might not attract the credit the answer may other wise deserve.  Without it it looks just a bit _too clever_ (http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/kernighans-lever/)

Comment: @Clifford Added some explanation. I believe it would suffice now. Thanks for the advise

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is perhaps to use a larger intermediate type:

```
int m = (int)((long long)n * (n + 1) / 2) ;
```

It is not necessary to cast all operands since automatic type promotion will apply.

Comment: the problem is more general - what to use if the calculated type is long long itself.  `long long long`? :D

Comment: @PeterJ_01 :  In this case the question is very specific: _"knowing that n is an `int` <= 2^16 - 1"_. A "general" solution would be unnecessarily complex in this _specific_ case.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 : General solutions have been suggested by others (including you).  chqrlie however included clear explanation and compared the solution to others in his answer, so better in my opinion.  I need not duplicate that.

Answer (score 1):

and one more:

```
  int m =  (n/2 * n)  + ((n%2) * (n/2)) + (n/2) + (n%2);
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe

```
result = (n) * (n / 2) + (n & 1) * (n) + n / 2 ;
```